# Getting EXC_Bad_Access while scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I am getting EXC_BadAccess error message while i am scrolling tableview.

the following is the code i have done in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"customCellHistory";

    customCellHistory *cell=(customCellHistory*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCellHistory" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] ) {
                cell=(customCellHistory*)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cell.lb11.text=[cellArray1 objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    cell.lbl2.text=[cellArray2 objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I can sense the problem is arising due to some mistake in the above code.

I used CustomCell in the above code to display a customized cell.

can anyone tell me what wrong have i done in this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try the following code, dont forget to `set the cell identifier` in you custom XIB to `customCellHistory`

At the top

```
#import "customeCellHistory.h"
```

then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCellHistory";

    customCellHistory *cell = (customCellHistory *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCellHistory" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.lb11.text=[cellArray1 objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    cell.lbl2.text=[cellArray2 objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting the error "[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance".

Comment: Did you create the custom cell NIB and set its cellIdentifier to `customCellHistory`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to arise from the strange loop you have. Use the last object method to set cell from the nib.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing a cell and then changing the cell in your loop which probably leads to a cell not existing where you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCellHistory" owner:self options:nil];
```

You don't need that code. Just register the nib with the table view, earlier on:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCellHistory" bundle:nil]
 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"customCellHistory"];
```

Now when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, the nib will be loaded and the cell will be delivered, if there is no spare cell in the reuse pile. This ensures that you consistently have a cell and that it is the right kind of cell. Use the methods the framework gives you.

Comment: This depends on your deployment target setting. If you only support iOS 5 and 6, your answer is correct, but if you want to support iOS 4.x, the original code is the way to do it.

Comment: The original code may be *a* way to do it on iOS 4. But that doesn't make it *the* way. Here is another way, the way I used to use on iOS 4 (a lot safer and simpler than the OP's code, and more efficient too): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS4bookExamples/p516p531addCellSubviewsNibOutlets/p516addCellSubviewsNibOutlets/RootViewController.m